# How would I log current Response data before send to the client in Nestjs via NestInterceptor

Tags: node.js, nestjs, interceptor

[image]

Here I'm able to check the request Object instead of the response which is sent by the Controller.

from Response, I'm able to get all these properties:

1. statusCode
2. statusMessage
   etc.
   How can I trace the response body before send to the client?

Answer (score 0):

You can *partially* rely on the `response` object obtained by `context.switchToHttp().getResponse()`, however there are a few caveats to be aware of:

1. The `statusCode` may not yet be set properly. If there is an error or there is an `@HttpCode()` decorator that changes the status, you'll need some custom code to try and figure it out, and even then an Exception Filter could still modify it to be something else. This is thesnippet I use in my [Ogma Interceptor](https://ogma.jaymcdoniel.dev/en/nestjs/interceptor/):

```js
  getStatus(context: ExecutionContext, inColor: boolean, error?: HttpException | Error): string {
    let status: number;
    const res = this.getResponse(context);
    status = res.statusCode;
    const reflectStatus = this.reflector.get<number>(HTTP_CODE_METADATA, context.getHandler());
    status = reflectStatus || status;
    if (error) {
      status = this.determineStatusCodeFromError(error);
    }
    return inColor ? this.wrapInColor(status) : status.toString();
  }
```

2. You should use an alternate form of `tap` to properly handle both success and errors

```js
tap({
  next: successTapHandler,
  error: errorTapHandler,
})
```

3. There's no need to `await ctx.getResponse()`, it's not a promise. Just a direct helper to get the response object from the `ExecutionContext`'s `args`

[You're more than welcome to read up on how my `OgmaInterceptor` logs each request](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma/blob/main/packages/nestjs-module/src/interceptor/ogma.interceptor.ts) with a (mostly) appropriate status code and the body's length.

Comment: above solution is not working as I described

Comment: @RohitSengar what are you particularly missing from this solution?